# Configurable validation in Spring MVC

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I am using Spring validation mechanism with annotations. Validation must be configurable in `messages_en.properties`. For this purpose serves the entry `password.min=4` in this file.

How to configure @Size validator according to settings in `messageSource` bean?

```
public class SubmitModel {

@Size(min = "#{new Integer(messageSource[login.ok])}") //does not work. @Size expects integer value
private String password;

}
```

Bean configuration:

```xml
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>lang\messages</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I already tried to configure the static constants but here again a constant expression is expected.
FYI, this mechanism is needed to validate the incoming requests in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/device/{devicename}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/xml")
@ResponseBody
public String handleRequest(@PathVariable("devicename") String devicename, @Valid @ModelAttribute SubmitModel model, BindingResult errors) throws UCLoginException { ... }
```

Typical example where the password must longer than *`login.ok`* value: `http://my.domain.com:8080/submit/device/SPAxxxxx?name=adam&password=454321`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The values of Annotation attributes have to be constants and cannot be changed after compilation. Use a custom [`Validator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) if you need that level of customizable configuration.

```
@Inject
private SubmitModelValidator customValidator;

public String handleRequest(@PathVariable("devicename") String devicename, @Valid @ModelAttribute SubmitModel model, BindingResult errors) throws UCLoginException { ... }
    customValidator.validate(model, errors);
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Where `SubmitModelValidator` is a `Validator` implementation for which you've created a bean and set all sorts of fields from properties with `@Value`.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It spared me a lot of time.